# How to prevent malicious Meteor subscriptions using check

Tags: security, meteor

I found an important security fault in my meteor app regarding subscriptions (maybe methods are also affected by this).

Even though I use the `check` package and `check()` assuring that the correct parameters data types are received inside the publication, I have realised that if a user maliciously subscribes to that subscription with wrong parameter data types it is affecting all other users that are using the same subscription because the meteor server is not running the publication while the malicious user is using incorrect parameters.

How can I prevent this?

Packages used:

```
aldeed:collection2-core@2.0.1
audit-argument-checks@1.0.7
mdg:validated-method
```

and npm

`import { check, Match } from 'meteor/check';`

Server side:

```
Meteor.publish('postersPub', function postersPub(params) {
    check(params, {
        size: String,
        section: String,
    });
    return Posters.find({
        section: params.section,
        size: params.size === 'large' ? 'large' : 'small',
    }, {
        // fields: { ... }
        // sort: { ... }
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
// in the template:
Meteor.subscribe('postersPub', { size: 'large', section: 'movies' });

// Malicious user in the browser console:
Meteor.subscribe('postersPub', { size: undefined, section: '' });
```

Problem: The malicious user subscription is preventing all other users of getting answer from their `postersPub` subscriptions.

Extra note: I've also tried wrapping the check block AND the whole publication with a `try catch` and it doesn't change the effect. The error disappears from the server console, but the other users keep being affected and not getting data from the subscription that the malicious user is affecting.

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing the code, but why you are not checking that client send a correct data. Also if your publication is user related you need to user `this.userId`

Comment: Hi Maxim, the pub is not user related

Comment: @MaximPokrovskii I've added more code and explanation

Comment: also worth to say that the meteor server doesn't break, but it does block data being sent from that affected publication

Comment: You mention an error, but don't include it in your question. What is that error and how does it affect the other users? You can always further validate the arguments in your publication.

Comment: I'd personally just add `if ( params.size ) { // do a code}`
Actualy your code seems fine. Subscription with `{size: undefined}` should return small sizes cause of `size: params.size === 'large' ? 'large' : 'small'`



It is also shouldn't affect others clients.

Can you post an error you get?

Comment: Well, stupidly enough, I found that the problem was a typo on the template, which was causing all the clients to have the same subscription blocked. The intended code was something like `stringContainingNumbers || ''` but one pipe was missing, turning the string into a number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Check method and empty strings

There is one thing to know about `check` and strings which is, that it accepts empty strings like `''` which you basically showed in your malicious example.

Without guarantee to solve your publication issue I can at least suggest you to modify your `check` code and include a check for non-empty Strings.

A possible approach could be:

```js
import { check, Match } from 'meteor/check';

const nonEmptyString = Match.Where(str => typeof str === 'string' && str.length > 0);
```

which then can be used in `check` like so:

```js
check(params, {
    size: nonEmptyString,
    section: nonEmptyString,
});
```

#### Even more strict checks

You may be even stricter with accepted parameters and reduce them to a subset of valid entries. For example:

```js
const sizes = ['large', 'small'];
const nonEmptyString = str => typeof str === 'string' && str.length > 0;
const validSize = str => nonEmptyString(str) && sizes.indexOf( str) > -1;

check(params, {
    size: Match.Where(validSize),
    section: Match.Where(nonEmptyString),
});
```

Note, that this also helps you to avoid query logic based on the parameter. You can change the following code

```js
const posters = Posters.find({
    section: params.section,
    size: params.size === 'large' ? 'large' : 'small',
}, {
    // fields: { ... }
    // sort: { ... }
});
```

to

```js
const posters = Posters.find({
    section: params.section,
    size: params.size,
}, {
    // fields: { ... }
    // sort: { ... }
});
```

because the method does anyway accept only one of `large` or `small` as parameters.

#### Fallback on undefined cursors in publications

Another pattern that can support you preventing publication errors is to call `this.ready()` if the collection returned no cursor (for whatever reason, better is to write good tests to prevent you from these cases).

```js
const posters = Posters.find({
    section: params.section,
    size: params.size === 'large' ? 'large' : 'small',
}, {
    // fields: { ... }
    // sort: { ... }
});

// if we have a cursor with count
if (posters && posters.count && posters.count() >= 0)
    return posters;

// else signal the subscription
// that we are ready
this.ready();
```

#### Combined code example

Applying all of the above mentioned pattern would make your function look like this:

```js
import { check, Match } from 'meteor/check';

const sizes = ['large', 'small'];
const nonEmptyString = str => typeof str === 'string' && str.length > 0;
const validSize = str => nonEmptyString(str) && sizes.indexOf( str) > -1;



Meteor.publish('postersPub', function postersPub(params) {
    check(params, {
        size: Match.Where(validSize),
        section: Match.Where(nonEmptyString),
    });


    const posters = Posters.find({
        section: params.section,
        size: params.size,
    }, {
        // fields: { ... }
        // sort: { ... }
    });

    // if we have a cursor with count
    if (posters && posters.count && posters.count() >= 0)
        return posters;

    // else signal the subscription
    // that we are ready
    this.ready();
});
```

#### Summary

I for myself found that with good `check` matches and `this.ready()` the problems with publications have been reduced to a minimum in my applications.

Comment: @w3jimmy does this help you to solve your issue somehow?

Comment: Thanks @Jankapunkt, I found the reason for my problem, but your answer is good enough to mark as correct (see comment above)